# jQuery Select2 refresh data with Knockout observableArray

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-select2, observable

I have a knockout `observableArray` that is bound as datasource to the select2 plugin.

```
var typeahead = $view.select2({
                formatSelection: format,
                formatResult: format,
                allowClear: true,
                multiple: false,
                data: self.dataSource(),
                //minimumInputLength: 1,
                //query: function (queryObj) {
                //    //queryObj.callback(function () { return CDSData; });
                //    //console.log(queryObj.term);
                //    self.searchText(queryObj.term);
                //    //alert(self.dataSource())
                //    //queryObj.callback(self.dataSource());
                //}
            });
```

I have a function to change the `observableArray` (ultimately datasource of select2) based on text entered by user into select2 textbox.

That function successfully changes my `observableArray`, but the suggestion list is not getting refreshed with the newer datasource.

Note that I cannot use Ajax features for this.

Comment: We will need a small repro of your scenario to be able to help you.

Comment: Suppose, There is a dropdown list of countries [ India, Australia, America] and select2 provide suggestion for the cities of selected country. On dropdown (Country) change, Suggestion list should refreshed. The data property of select2 is bounded to an ObservableArray of cities. So, when country selection changes, I reassign ObservableArray with newer cities list. Ultimately I need to refresh datasource of select2. but its not happening with current implementation

Comment: I meant to suggest you'd edit your question, and add enough code for us to *minimally* reproduce your situation. See [this help-center topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance. Without it we'd be guessing at your situation / problem, and hence be guessing at solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is actually binding when you pass the array dataSource(), you are not sending the observable array at this point but the actual array itself.  I also don't think this triggers KO to bind, there's not element for it to bind to when passed as a JSON object to select2.

I would suggest creating an observable on the dataSource observableArray and then use jquery to find $view and update the data attribute.